# 301 Redirect .htaccess - convert URL ending in .html to same but convert to directory name without ending in .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would really appreciate help with the following 301 Redirect using Apache .htaccess as I am stuck on how to do this:

I need to convert:
http://blog.domain.com/2015/03/filename.html

to:
http://www.domain.com/blog/filename/

There are many to do from the original file structure. The year and month that make up the original URL, change and go back each month and for several years. i.e. 2015/03, 2015/02, 2015/01, 2014/12 etc...

The ending filename.html needs to be the name of the new directory name without the ending .html and adding a closing '/'

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule http://blog.domain.com/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include the `http://domainname/` part of the URL in the regex of a rewrite rule, only the `2015/03/filename.html` part is used for any matching.

You could try using mod_alias instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([^/.]+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1/
```

Or if you already have rewrite rules, better to stick with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule [0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([^/.]+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. For others, I used the 2nd suggestion of RewriteCond etc.